Fish: To match both dot and non-dot files when wildcarding

Hidden files (where the name begins with a dot) are not considered when wildcarding unless the wildcard string has a dot in that place. E.g., ~/.* matches all hidden files and directories in your home directory.
https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html

But is it possible to match both dot and non-dot files in Fish? In other words, if ls folder1/ returns .file1 file2 file3, how can I move or copy all the three files to folder2 in one step? mv folder1/* folder2/ doesn't move .file1 for me.

Only half joking: bash -O dotglob -c 'mv folder1/* folder2/'. I can't see from skimming the fish shell documentation that it has anything similar to dotglob as a shell option.

Instead of *, you could use {.,}* (to catch both files that start with . or any other character).
For instance:
mv folder1/{.,}* folder2/


Wow, thanks a lot, Aviro!

Would this not fail with an error if there were no hidden names in the source directory?

@Kusalananda It seems there is no such an issue, macOS 14.5

@Kusalananda not according to my tests. As long as there's at least one work expanded (either hidden or non-hidden) it doesn't fail. BTW, it's also worth mentioning that as opposed to other shells like bash, it doesn't even expand . and ...

Ah, I see, then it must treat {.,} as part of the globbing pattern.  Other shells would first expand folder1/{.,}* into folder1/.* and folder1/*, and then do the filename globbing, but ls folder1/.* folder1/* generates an error even in the fish shell if the directory does not contain hidden names (or only contains hidden names).  The given solution still fails on completely empty directories though.

@aviro Sorry, but does your bash shell expand * to . and .. with dotglob set?!

@Kusalananda no, I meant if you use {.,}* in bash and dotglob is disabled (and GLOBIGNORE in not set), it will expand to . and ... And yes, my solution will fail on completely empty directories, which is expected, I guess. The same will happen with any other shell.

@aviro You are probably referring to bash release 5.1 or earlier then. The 5.2 release has globskipdots enabled by default (that's a new shell option in that relase).
